# Octave does not plot the function

Tags: plot, graph, octave

I am preparing a graph of binding protein behavior.

```
x = linspace(0,1,101)
y = ( x.*2.2*(10^-4))/(( x.+6.25*(10^-2))*(x.+2.2*(10^-2)))
plot(x,y)
```

Should result a bell curve(maybe) or a curve but i am getting a linear graph. I had checked with other software and resulting curve that function. Any help please?

Comment: What does ` x.2.2(10^-4)` mean?

Comment: is x.*2.2(10^-4) but the editor didn t appear properly

Comment: Why not just write `x.*2.2e-4` ?

Comment: "non-conformant arguments". basically you need `.*` instead of `*`

Comment: So what exactly is the mistake and does not appear curve? Could please show me correct code?please?

Comment: `y = ( x.*2.2e-4)./(( x.+6.25e-2).*(x.+2.2e-2))`

Comment: Thank you Tasos and Michael O. ! Have a nice day

Comment: @Adam, the way this is written, it makes such an error very difficult to spot. Consider writing this more clearly, over several lines, and with appropriate spacing; the interpreter would then tell you exactly where you have an error, very clearly.

Answer (score 1):

### What's wrong

You want to use `./` array division, not `/` matrix division.

### How to debug this

First, get some spaces up in here so it's easier to read. And add semicolons to suppress that big output.

```
x = linspace(0, 1, 101);
y = (x.*2.2*(10^-4)) / ( ( x.+6.25*(10^-2)) * (x.+2.2*(10^-2)) );
plot(x, y)
```

Then stick it in a function for easier debugging:

```
function my_plot_of_whatever
x = linspace(0, 1, 101);
y = (x.*2.2*(10^-4)) / ( ( x.+6.25*(10^-2)) * (x.+2.2*(10^-2)) );
plot(x, y)
```

Now try it:

```
>> my_plot_of_whatever
error: my_plot_of_whatever: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x101, op2 is 1x101)
error: called from
    my_plot_of_whatever at line 3 column 3
```

When you get a complaint like that about `*` or `/`, it usually means you're doing matrix operations when you really want the elementwise "array" operations `.*` and `./`. Fix that and try it again:

```
>> my_plot_of_whatever
>>
```

[image: bad linear plot]

So what's going on here? Let's use the debugger!

```
>> dbstop in my_plot_of_whatever at 4
ans =  4
>> my_plot_of_whatever
stopped in /Users/janke/Documents/octave/my_plot_of_whatever.m at line 4
4: plot(x, y)
debug> whos
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  =====
        x           1x101                      808  double
        y           1x1                          8  double
```

Aha. Your `y` is scalar, so it's using the same Y value for every X value. That's because you're using `/` matrix division, when you really want `./` array division. Fix that:

```
function my_plot_of_whatever
x = linspace(0, 1, 101);
y = (x.*2.2*(10^-4)) ./ ( ( x.+6.25*(10^-2)) .* (x.+2.2*(10^-2)) );
plot(x, y)
```

Bingo.

[image]